# Comprehensive list of discrete Fourier transforms

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, book-recommendation, fourier-transform

What is the state of known exact solutions for the discrete Fourier transform (DFT)?

Is there any good resource? Typically, the lists I find just have the geometric series, derivation of it, delta function and exponentials. Is this all there is?

Comment: What geometric series are you referring to?

Comment: @littleO x(n)=a^n with 'a' constant.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "discrete Fourier transform"? Often this term refers to the operator $F:\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ which changes basis to the discrete Fourier basis (which is a basis of eigenvectors for the cyclic shift operator). But since you mentioned the delta function, this doesn't seem to be what you're referring to.

Comment: @littleO I mean this one https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform . Delta function was a bit misleading, I mean Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$

Comment: It's not really clear what is meant by an "exact solution". The discrete Fourier transform simply changes basis from the standard basis of $\mathbb C^n$ to the discrete Fourier basis. If $F$ is the change of basis matrix, then the DFT of a vector $x \in \mathbb C^n$ is just $Fx$. That is already pretty explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the $z$-transform for a causal signal $x[n]$ is given by:
$$X(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n}$$
where $z=e^{j\omega}$, and the DFT of a signal with finite (say, $N$) samples is derived from:
$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi n}N k\right)$$
So basically, the DFT is the $z$-transform evaluated at $z=e^{j\omega_k}$, where $\omega_k:=\frac{2\pi k}N$. i.e.
$$X[k] = X(z) \bigg|_{z=e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N} k}}$$
You may also take a look at [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/28466). Now if you are looking for a comprehensive table of DFTs, your search can be narrowed down by considering this fact and looking for a comprehensive [table of $z$-transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs) instead. (Also [this one](http://www.ece.utah.edu/~ece3500/ece3500_DiscreteTransforms.pdf))

Comment: In case the second link is inaccessible, there's a copy of it [here](http://pfister.ee.duke.edu/courses/ece485/dtft_table.pdf).